# call webservice using jquery

Tags: java, jquery, web-services, jax-ws

I have built a java webservice and I am trying to call it using jquery ajax
and I cant get a simple output.. what I get is the HTML page that is generated when calling WSDL

here is the JSP code

```
checkLogin = function () {

             $.ajax({
                url : 'loginWS?method=checklogin',
                data : {
                    userName : $("#userName").val(),
                    password : $("#password").val()
                },
                success : function(responseText) {
                   $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(500);
                   alert(responseText);                       
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(500);
                }
            });
```

and this is the java webservice

```
    @WebService(serviceName = "loginWS")
public class loginWS {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "checkLogin")
    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public String checkLogin(@WebParam(name = "userName") String userName, @WebParam(name = "password") String password) {

        if(userName.equalsIgnoreCase("admin") && password.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")){             
          return "success";
        }else{
            return "fail";
        }
    }
```

All I get is the following result

```
    <html>

<head><title>

Web Services

</title></head>

<body>

<h1>Web Services</h1>

<table width='100%' border='1'>

<tr>

<td>

Endpoint

</td>

<td>

Information

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>

<table border="0"><tr><td>Service Name:</td><td>{http://login.services/}loginWS</td></tr><tr><td>Port Name:</td><td>{http://login.services/}loginWSPort</td></tr></table>

</td>

<td>

<table border="0"><tr><td>Address:</td><td>http://localhost:8081/CSHS/loginWS</td></tr><tr><td>WSDL:</td><td><a href="http://localhost:8081/CSHS/loginWS?wsdl">http://localhost:8081/CSHS/loginWS?wsdl</a></td></tr><tr><td>Implementation class:</td><td>services.login.loginWS</td></tr></table>

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</body>

</html>
```

How can I get a simple result like "success" or "fail"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web service is JAX-WS web service. You cannot call JAX-WS web service without creating a client(i.e. directly via jQuery).

There are two ways you can go about this :

1. Create the client for your web service(using WSDL) and then create simple servlet which in turn calls your web service on server side. You can call this Servlet via jQuery. Use below link to create a web service client :

   http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html

   OR
2. Create a RESTful web service which you can directly call using http(via jQuery). For REST web service, see the JAVA EE tutorial described in below link :

   https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipzz.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
checkLogin = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'loginWS?method=checklogin',
        data : JSON.stringify({
            userName : $("#userName").val(),
            password : $("#password").val()
        }),
        success : function(responseText) {
            $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(500);
            alert(responseText);                       
        },
        error: function (err) {
            $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(500);
            alert(err);
        }
    });
};
```

Passing an object as data, despite declaring the data type as JSON in the web service header, has never worked for me.  Passing it as a string, using `JSON.stringify()` has always solved my problem.

This was with a C# web service, so it may not be relevant.  If not I'll delete this post, rather than be misleading to people who stumble here in the future.

Comment: No it didnt work.. I still got the same error.. even when I try to call the webservice in the browser, i got the same error
http://localhost:8081/CSHS/loginWS?method=checklogin&userName=admin&password123
I got HTML content rather that string